# linux java mysql source command Unknown database

Tags: java, mysql, ubuntu-18.04

I'm using Java on Ubuntu to connect mysql server

this is the java code:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mysql -u user -ppass -e \"source filename "\"");
```

but it always gave me this error

```
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'filename'
```

It worked in windows 10 and by directly command "mysql -u user -ppass -e "source filename " in the terminal of Ubuntu-18.04

I'm new to Linux, Any Ideas?

Comment: You need to create the database first, before using it

Comment: Try to use a [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).

Comment: Default database port 3306, are you sure of that your database is listening on port 3306?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This variant of `exec` relies on tokenizing the command (thus splitting on spaces) and will fail for non trivial command line strings, containing spaces. Use the alternate form of `exec`, building the arguments array yourself:

```
String[] args = {
            "mysql", "-u", "user", "-ppass", "-e", "\"source filename\""
    };
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(args);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Runtime.exec("mysql db_name <"fource file_name");
```

for instance:

```
Runtime.exec("mysql db_name </home/ferrakkem/download/tpch/queries/Q1.sql");
```

more details : [check out this documentations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: I doubt that `Runtime.exec()` does shell style redirections?

Comment: this is my code Runtime.exec("mysql -u user -ppass </home/alan/cb/sqls/27712-1-1531818636435.sql") , but it still gave me : ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database '</home/alan/cb/sqls/27712-1-1531818636435.sql'